# Ignore empty textboxes criteria from userform if user doesnt want to use them, and filter data with the other textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to vba and i am trying to create a userform that searches various data for real estate plots stored in a spreadsheet. I have some textboxes and comboboxes that the user will use to filter data according to his search requirements.The search results are then listed in a listbox. I can create code for the userform, for the case that the user uses all textboxes and comboboxes. I would need help with the code in the case the user does not want to use all search criteria but some of them. In this case the code must ignore all textboxes or comboboxes that are empty and use the rest. It is obvious that there are many search combinations and it is not possible to code each of them.

```
Private Sub cmdsearchplotpropertysearch_Click()
Dim lowdate As Long
Dim highdate As Long
Dim highprice As Long
Dim lowprice As Long
Dim higharea As Long
Dim lowarea As Long

Dim LPrice As MSForms.ComboBox, Hprice As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim LArea As MSForms.ComboBox, HArea As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim LDate As MSForms.TextBox, HDate As MSForms.TextBox

Set LPrice = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertypricemin
Set Hprice = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertypricemax
Set LArea = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertyareamin
Set HArea = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertyareamax
Set LDate = Me.txtsearchplotpropertydatemin
Set HDate = Me.txtsearchplotpropertydatemax

'Check for empty inputs!
If LPrice = Empty Or IsNull(LPrice) Then
   lowprice = 0
Else
   lowprice = CLng(LPrice)
End If

If Hprice = Empty Or IsNull(Hprice) Then
   highprice = 1000000000
Else
   highprice = CLng(Hprice)
End If

If LArea = Empty Or IsNull(LArea) Then
   lowarea = 0
Else
   lowarea = CLng(LArea)
End If

If HArea = Empty Or IsNull(HArea) Then
   higharea = 1000000
Else
   higharea = CLng(HArea)
End If

If LDate = Empty Or IsNull(LDate) Then
   lowdate = 1
Else
   lowdate = CLng(CDate(LDate))
End If

If HDate = Empty Or IsNull(HDate) Then
   highdate = CLng(Date)
Else
   highdate = CLng(CDate(HDate))
End If

'Check for correct ranges!
If lowprice > highprice Then
        MsgBox "Ðáñáêáëþ åéóÜãåôå óùóôÜ ôï Ýõñïò ôéìþí ôïõ áêéíÞôïõ !",       vbCritical, "ËÜèïò Ýõñïò ôéìþí"
Me.Hide
Worksheets("SOFTWARE").Activate
Exit Sub

ElseIf lowarea > higharea Then

MsgBox "Ðáñáêáëþ åéóÜãåôå óùóôÜ ôéò åðéöÜíåéåò ôïõ áêéíÞôïõ !", vbCritical, "ËÜèïò Ýõñïò åðéöáíåéþí"
Me.Hide
Worksheets("SOFTWARE").Activate
Exit Sub
ElseIf lowdate > highdate Then

MsgBox "Ðáñáêáëþ åéóÜãåôå óùóôÜ ôéò çìåñïìçíßåò !", vbCritical, "ËÜèïò çìåñïìçíßåò"
Me.Hide
Worksheets("SOFTWARE").Activate
Exit Sub
End If

Dim i As Long
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim PLOTS As Worksheet
Set PLOTS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PLOTS")

Dim Resultlistbox As MSForms.ListBox
Set Resultlistbox = plotresultsfrm.lstboxplots


finalrow = Sheets("PLOTS").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Resultlistbox.Clear



For i = 3 To finalrow

If PLOTS.Cells(i, 5) >= lowprice And PLOTS.Cells(i, 5) <= highprice _
And PLOTS.Cells(i, 38) >= lowarea And Cells(i, 38) <= higharea _
And PLOTS.Cells(i, 2) >= lowdate And PLOTS.Cells(i, 2) <= highdate Then
    With Resultlistbox
        .AddItem PLOTS.Cells(i, 2)
        .List(Resultlistbox.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(i, 5)
        .List(Resultlistbox.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
        .List(Resultlistbox.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(i, 15)
    End With
End If
Next i

plotresultsfrm.Show
Worksheets("SOFTWARE").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code runs but you get unexpected results then there might be (but I can not verify this and there are multiple other possible causes) with the offset for table headers. Imagine you have two tables, where one has headers and the second doesn't and is just a simple data table.

Consider the following loop:

```
For i = 2 To 500 'I've started at 2 because of the headers
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        MsgBox "Rows " & i & " on sheet 1 and 2 are equal."
    End If
    'In the above if statement I've compensated for the fact that the
    'second sheet has no headers for the data and I want to compare the
    'same rows i.e. the first row of actual data
Next i
```

### Revised answer

I was thinking about my answer and found it to be confusing here is the code with the alterations made, I have attempted to make it more legible but that means I've made a few changes, code should still run because I've not changed the names of the forms or controls. I made the assumption that this code is inside a sub on the userform searchplotpropertyfrm, if that is not the case replace all instances of `Me.` with `searchplotpropertyfrm.`

```
    Dim LowDate As Long, HighDate As Long
    Dim HighPrice As Long, LowPrice As Long
    Dim HighArea As Long, LowArea As Long

    Dim LPrice As msforms.ComboBox, Hprice As msforms.ComboBox
    Dim LArea As msforms.ComboBox, HArea As msforms.ComboBox
    Dim LDate As msforms.TextBox, HDate As msforms.TextBox

    Set LPrice = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertypricemin
    Set Hprice = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertypricemax
    Set LArea = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertyareamin
    Set HArea = Me.cmboxsearchplotpropertyareamax
    Set LDate = Me.txtsearchplotpropertydatemin
    Set HDate = Me.txtsearchplotpropertydatemax

    Dim SOFTWARE As Worksheet
    Set SOFTWARE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Software")

    'The if statements below determine if the inputs are empty or not, If they are empty
    'the corresponding variable is still given a value, but one that you know the highest
    'or lowest value of the variable will never exceed
    If LPrice = Empty Or IsNull(LPrice) Then
        LowPrice = 0
    Else
        LowPrice = CLng(LPrice)
    End If

    If Hprice = Empty Or IsNull(HPrice) Then
        HighPrice = 1000000000
    Else
        HighPrice = CLng(Hprice)
    End If

    If LArea = Empty Or IsNull(LArea) Then
        LowArea = 0
    Else
        LowArea = CLng(LArea)
    End If

    If HArea = Empty Or IsNull(HArea) Then
        HighArea = 1000
    Else
        HighArea = CLng(HArea)
    End If

    If LDate = Empty Or IsNull(LDate) Then
        LowDate = 1
    Else
        LowDate = CLng(CDate(LDate))
    End If

    If HDate = Empty Or IsNull(HDate) Then
        HighDate = CLng(Date)
    Else
        HighDate = CLng(CDate(HDate))
    End If

    'Checks if the ranges are correct
    If LowPrice > HighPrice Then
        MsgBox "Please enter plot price range correctly!", vbCritical, "Invalid plot pricerange"
        Me.Hide
        SOFTWARE.Activate
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf LowArea > HighArea Then
        MsgBox "Please enter plot area range correctly!", vbCritical, "Invalid plot area range"
        Me.Hide
        SOFTWARE.Activate
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf LowDate > HighDate Then
        MsgBox "Please enter plot input dates correctly!", vbCritical, "Invalid date range"
        Me.Hide
        SOFTWARE.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim i As Long
    Dim FinalRow As Long

    Dim PLOTS As Worksheet
    Set PLOTS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PLOTS")

    Dim ResultListbox As msforms.ListBox
    Set ResultListbox = plotresultsfrm.lstboxplots

    FinalRow = PLOTS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    ResultListbox.Clear

    For i = 3 To FinalRow
        If PLOTS.Cells(i, 5) >= LowPrice And PLOTS.Cells(i, 5) <= HighPrice _
                And PLOTS.Cells(i, 38) >= LowArea And PLOTS.Cells(i, 38) <= HighArea _
                And PLOTS.Cells(i, 6) >= LowDate And PLOTS.Cells(i, 6) <= HighDate Then
            With ResultListbox
                .AddItem CStr(PLOTS.Cells(i, 2))
                .List(ResultListbox.ListCount - 1, 1) = PLOTS.Cells(i, 5)
                .List(ResultListbox.ListCount - 1, 2) = PLOTS.Cells(i, 3)
                .List(ResultListbox.ListCount - 1, 3) = PLOTS.Cells(i, 15)
            End With
        End If
    Next i

    plotresultsfrm.Show
```

Note that x's in the if statement to find which items to add to the listbox still need to be replaced with the columnindex of the column with the plot dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used the code but I get an error "Invalid use of null" for the CLng(Lprice) in the first if statement which checks empty inputs. I also checked that i have the same problem to the rest CLng(Hprice) etc. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: If I understand correctly, It gets past the `If LPrice = Empty Then` statement and the `LowPrice = CLng(LPrice)` line was highlighted when you pressed debug on the error dialog. What is the exact input you use on the form?. I have tested the code with numbers only without any formatting such as  thousand separators or currency signs.

Comment: Yes you are right, it highlights the LowPrice=CLng(LPrice). The values that i use in the comboboxes come from a worksheet range and until now they have no formatting and they range from 5000 to 1000000.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error you're getting, could you show me the `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` of the `searchplotpropertyfrm` (you can add them to your question by editing it)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. The only way I could reproduce `Runtime error 94 invalid us of null` with the code as I wrote it, was to replace the `ComboBox` with a `ListBox` on the UserForm. From your code I assumed that the `LowPrice, HighPrice, LowArea, and HighArea` inputs on the UserForm were ComboBoxes, but that, I must admit was an assumption. You can add `or IsNull(LPrice)` to the code to work around the `Invalid use of Null` set the search boundaries accordingly, I've updated my answer to include these statements.

Comment: The easiest and fastest way would be if I could take a look at the entire document and get an understanding of all that is going on in the document but I would understand if that is not desirable on your end. If you want to, you can send the document to silentrevolution@hmamail.com (which is a temporary address), or upload and post a public link

Comment: I am trying to understand my mistake but seriously I have no idea why the code is not working properly. Lowprice highprice etc inputs are in comboboxes. I used isnull(......) and I get no runtime error now. The problem is that I get weird results. Even when I place some values in the comboboxes of my userform which should produce a known result, I check that I get back the largest or smallest values for lowprice, highprice etc. and my listbox produces random results. I updated the code I used in case you can give me some more help. Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all @Yannis, we all had to learn at some point. I've update my answer because the comment is too short to answer,